# 名前が変えられたBluetoothデバイスを検出したい

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth

Bluetooth LEなデバイスのローカルネームを変更して、その後に再び
  CBCentralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options: と
  CBCentralManagerDelegate centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:advertisementData:RSSI:
を使って検索すると、見つかったデバイスの名前が変更前のままになっています。

iOS 8で、変更後の名前を取得する方法はありますか?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

デバイスが見つかったときに呼ばれるメソッド、

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central
 didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral
     advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData
                  RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
```

の peripheral.name にはOSがキャッシュしている名前が入っているようですが、
`advertisementData[@"kCBAdvDataLocalName"]`にはアドバタイズパケットの
ローカルネームが入っているようです。

ちなみに、接続に成功するとperipheral.nameは変更後の名前に更新されるようです。